# Hibernate Code generation reverse engineering not working

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jboss-tools

I have set up all the things to run hibernate code generation.
I have done it before, it was working for me.
I have gone through the steps at http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/

But it's not working this time.

It shows me Databse and tables when I extract hibernate configuration in Hibernate view.
When I run the code generation configuration it quickly gets completed(I have only 4 tables in MySQL databse). But no code is generated at output directory.
No error comes in error log. Nothing seems to happen.

Anyone has faced the same issue?

Comment: Please post some code or detailed steps that you followed. Did you correctly configure you output directory? Double check if you followed step 3 correctly.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed to select the check mark in step 3 "Reverse Engineering from JDBC connection". Thanks for pointing to it. You are great @NikhilTalreja

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to inform others,
The issue in my case was, I was providing a reveng.xml file in step 3.
I have written table names in CAPS in this file and in My SQL they are in small.

This was the original issue.
reveng.xml should have table names in same case as in Databse.

Comment: Removing reveng.xml worked for me. After that code generation worked. Interesting: after re-adding reveng.xml it (still) worked ... (using Hibernate Tools 5.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

Double check if you followed step 3 correctly

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and solve it by checking Reverse engineer from JDBC Connections and setup reveng.xml.

I don't know why this checkbox is unchecked in default.